# How to call server side function from client side with asp.net?

Tags: .net

I need to call server side function from client side using JavaScript. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you really expect people to answer this question? Do some research yourself and then come back with specific problems if you have any.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can do an Ajax call to achieve this!

Google for how to use ajax to call server side functions from JavaScript.

Comment: i got answer by refering

http://aspalliance.com/1294_CodeSnip_Handle_Browser_Close_Event_on_the_ServerSide.1

thanks mahesh

Comment: This answer says "Ajax" and then says "Google it". It's correct in the sense that the question was too broad even in 2010, but this is not really an answer.