# Call server side function from client side javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to call server side function from client side - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279719/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-asp-net)
>   [Calling ASP.NET Code Behind function from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript)
>   [Calling ASP.NET server side method via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

hi guys,
     While loading an aspx page, how is it possible to call a server side method with the client side code?Can u show one example?

Comment: There are plenty of other questions asking this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You'll need ajax for this, one way or another. Either use ASP.NET's built-in 'page methods', or whip up something yourself; your best bet is to use something like jQuery to make the javascript part less painful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through and Ajax request. Since you're using asp.net here is a good starting point for some great [JavaScript Ajax libraries](http://www.asp.net/ajax?tabid) for it.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)'s also a simple example of how to make a simple Ajax request.

```
function sampleAjaxReq(){
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST","resource.asp",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("pname1=value1Henry&pname2=value2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a non-Ajax project, you can try System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.

Samples here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210%28VS.80%29.aspx
>
> http://www.ajaxmatters.com/2006/05/using-icallbackeventhandler-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate also with Web Services.