# Call an ASP.NET function from javascript with a client side parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Actually the code is self-explanatory.. I am trying to assign a javascript variable the falue of a form element, which needs to be formatted by a function on the server..

the below code does not work. it does not get the form element but rather assumes $('#formvalue').val() is the string I am passing in..

```
var myvar = '<%= MyNamespace.MyClass.MyFunction("' + $('#formvalue').val() + '") %>'
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call server side function from client side - asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279719/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-asp-net)

Comment: Maybe first get the value of the form element, and then send it to the server, format it, and get the response. With Jquery or PageMethods

Comment: is MyFunction() or can it be a WebMethod?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PageMethods to call a server function (public static WebMethod) from JavaScript.

Server-side function

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AbandonSession()
 {
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
 }
```

JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  function HandleClose() 
   {
     alert("Killing the session on the server!!");
      PageMethods.AbandonSession();
   }
   //]]>
</script>
```

Check this: http://aspalliance.com/1294_CodeSnip_Handle_Browser_Close_Event_on_the_ServerSide.all

Comment: So you could elaborate a little bit more on why you require it that way. And post context code.